# help with understanding strong relevant feature

Tags: classification, feature-selection

According to [Kohavi and John](https://ai.stanford.edu/~ronnyk/wrappers.pdf) (page 5), in the XOR problem feature $X_1$ is strongly relevant, but I suspect this statement.

The strong relevance definition implies $p(Y=y|X_i=x_i, S_i=s_i) \ne p(Y=y|S_i=s_i)$, this means there are some cases where knowledge of $X_i$ modified the probabilities of classifying $y$ under a certain class.

Let´s consider the $Y=0$ case. In this case, $p(Y=0|Si)=\frac48=\frac12$, considering all possible values of $S_i$ where $Y$ is $0$ (cases $0,1,6,7$ in table below). In this case, probability conditioned by $X_i$ is $p(Y=0|X_1=0,S_i)=\frac24=\frac12$ (cases $0,1$ out of possible $0,1,2,3$ cases), and $p(Y=0|X_1=1,S_i)=\frac24=\frac12$ (cases $6$ and $7$ out of possible cases $4,5,6,7$).

Conversely, for case $Y=1: p(Y=1|S_i)=\frac48=\frac12$ (cases $2, 3, 4$ and $5$). $X_i$ conditioned probability is $p(Y=1|X_1=0,S_i)=\frac24=\frac12$ (cases $2, 3$), $p(Y=1|X_1=1,S_i)=\frac24=\frac12$ (cases $4, 5$).

We see that in any of the possible cases the strong relevance condition holds, and we could say that feature $X_1$ is not strictly required to classify $Y$, although it may improve classification accuracy when added to feature set (for instance on cases $0,1,4,5$ adding $X_1$ improves classification accuracy).

Given that this paper is more than $20$ years old I strongly suspect that my understanding is flawed, what am I missing here?

Table

```
case    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  Y
0       0   0   0   1   1   0
1       0   0   1   1   0   0
2       0   1   0   0   1   1
3       0   1   1   0   0   1
4       1   0   0   1   1   1
5       1   0   1   1   0   1
6       1   1   0   0   1   0
7       1   1   1   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A feature $X_i$ is **strongly relevant** iff there exists some $x_i, y$, and $s_i$ for which $p(X_i=x_i, S_i=s_i)>0$ such that 
>   $$p(Y=y| X_i = x_i, S_i = s_i) \ne p(Y=y | S_i=s_i)$$

Since $P(X_1=0,(X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5)=(0,0,1,1))>0$,

$$P(Y=0|(X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5)=(0,0,1,1))=\frac12$$

but

$$P(Y=0|X_1=0,(X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5)=(0,0,1,1))=1,$$

$X_1$ is strongly relevant.

I think you did not specify your $s_i$.

Comment: Thanks, that's right on point, the definition specifies a certain value for Si rather than all of the possible ones.